# ¿Como sobrecargar CompareTo() para distintos atributos?

Tags: java

Tengo la clase producto de la que voy a hacer un array de objetos que quiero ordenar segun sus atributos. Implemento la interfaz Comparable y sobrescribo el metodo CompareTo. El metodo CompareTo solo puedo sobrescribirlo una vez por lo que usando sort solo puedo ordenarlo en base a un atributo. ¿Como puedo hacer para ordenar por diferentes atributos dependiendo de lo que el usuario elija?

```
public class Producto implements Comparable<Producto>{

private int id;
private String descripcion;
private double precio;

    @Override
public int compareTo(Producto p) {
    if(id < p.getId()){
        return -1;
    }
    if(id > p.getId()){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Llamada a la funcion sort:

```
Producto[] p;
Arrays.sort(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear clases separadas que implementen la interface `Comparator` en lugar de implementar la interface `Comparable` en `Producto`. Algo así:

```
class IdComparator implements Comparator<Producto> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Producto o1, Producto o2) {
        if (o1.getId() < o2.getId()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o1.getId() > o2.getId()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

class DescripcionComparator implements Comparator<Producto> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Producto o1, Producto o2) {
        return o1.getDescripcion().compareTo(o2.getDescripcion());
    }
}
```

Luego para usar las clases debes crear las instancias:

```
IdComparator idComparator = new IdComparator();
DescripcionComparator descripcionComparator = new DescripcionComparator();
```

Y por último para ordenar el Array debes hacerlo igual que lo estás haciendo pero con un parámetro más que sería la instancia del `Comparator` que quieres usar. Así:

```
Arrays.sort(p, idComparator); // Ordena por ID
Arrays.sort(p, descripcionComparator); // Ordena por descripción
```

Ahora haz lo mismo para el atributo `precio` y todos los otros atributos que contenga la clase `Producto`. Así ya puedes decidir dinámicamente por cual atributo ordenar el Array.

Comment: Por completitud, creo que sería bueno añadir que no es necesario escribir las clases, se pueden crear con expresiones lambda.