# ¿Cómo defino el elemento Comparator<> a usar para el método "compare()" y qué ventajas ofrece sobre "compareTo()"?

Tags: java, api

Tengo claro que **"compareTo()"** es un método implementado de la interfaz Comparable y nos permite definir un método de comparación entre **dos objetos de la misma clase**.

El método **"compare()"** es un método implementado de la interfaz Comparator que también nos permite comparar dos objetos entre sí los cuales **pueden ser de diferentes clases.**

Ahora bien, el método "compare()" sigue la estructura compElem.compare(a,b). **¿ Qué hace exactamente el elemento compElem ?¿ Cómo y dónde lo defino ?**

Si, por ejemplo, tengo que ordenar una lista de PersonasMalas en orden creciente de maldad dentro de la clase ArrayPersonasMalas, ¿ cómo se define el método "compare()" ?

Además de comparar elementos de diferentes clases, ¿ qué otras ventajas presenta Comparator frente a Comparable ?

Comment: [Esto debería resolver muchas de tus dudas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/339213/como-sobrecargar-compareto-para-distintos-atributos?rq=1)

Comment: Perfecto, creo que me vale. Ahora toca trabajar para afianzar la idea, pero creo que está muy bien explicado en ese enlace y lo he entendido. Gracias SJuan76